# Docker Compose exit code 137 for NGINX still after doubled my RAM

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I just doubled my RAM just to check if the error is actually because of RAM, but I don't think so, still failing with below issue after double the RAM

```
Attaching to nginx
nginx    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
nginx    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
nginx    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginx    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
nginx    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
nginx    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
nginx    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
nginx    | 2022/11/01 07:18:38 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
nginx    | 2022/11/01 07:18:38 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.23.2
nginx    | 2022/11/01 07:18:38 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 11.2.1 20220219 (Alpine 11.2.1_git20220219) 
nginx    | 2022/11/01 07:18:38 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.4.0-131-generic
nginx    | 2022/11/01 07:18:38 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
nginx    | 2022/11/01 07:18:38 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
nginx    | 2022/11/01 07:18:38 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 29
nginx    | 2022/11/01 07:18:38 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 30
nginx exited with code 137
```

compose file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.23.2-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /opt/aaa/conf/nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
      - /opt/aaa/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt/
      - /var/www/html/.well-known:/code/well-known
      - /etc/ssl/dhparam.pem:/etc/ssl/dhparam.pem
      - /opt/aaa/website/static:/code/static
      - /opt/aaa/install:/opt/install
    networks:
      - mehere

networks:
  personal:
    name: mehere
```

This is happening starting today, after a script just renewed my certs from letsencrypt.

Any idea please?

Comment: Have you checked the storage utilisation (Not RAM) ? use df -hP <storage_location>. 137 is memory related error. If you are using SQL/Postgres, please check the error logs also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just silly.
I had a script that removed that container `nginx` :-)